# Ignoring XML errors in Python

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am using XML minidom (xml.dom.minidom) in Python, but any error in the XML will kill the parser.
Is it possible to ignore them, like a browser for example?
I am trying to write a browser in Python, but it just throws an exception if the tags aren't fully compatible.

Comment: Good luck with the browser project!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a library called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), I think it's what you're looking for.
As you're trying to parse a invalid XML, the normal XML parser won't work. BeautifulSoup is more fail-tolerant, it can still extract information from invalid XML.

> Beautiful Soup is a Python HTML/XML
>   parser designed for quick turnaround
>   projects like screen-scraping. Three
>   features make it powerful:
>
> 1. Beautiful Soup won't choke if you give it bad markup. It yields a
>      parse tree that makes approximately as
>      much sense as your original document.
>      This is usually good enough to collect
>      the data you need and run away.
> 2. Beautiful Soup provides a few simple methods and Pythonic idioms for
>      navigating, searching, and modifying a
>      parse tree: a toolkit for dissecting a
>      document and extracting what you need.
>      You don't have to create a custom
>      parser for each application.
> 3. Beautiful Soup automatically converts incoming documents to Unicode
>      and outgoing documents to UTF-8. You
>      don't have to think about encodings,
>      unless the document doesn't specify an
>      encoding and Beautiful Soup can't
>      autodetect one. Then you just have to
>      specify the original encoding.
>
> Beautiful Soup parses anything you
>   give it, and does the tree traversal
>   stuff for you. You can tell it "Find
>   all the links", or "Find all the links
>   of class externalLink", or "Find all
>   the links whose urls match "foo.com",
>   or "Find the table heading that's got
>   bold text, then give me that text."

Comment: Four years later, I am still very thankful for this answer. You saved me from so much pain. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that while HTML looks like XML it is not XML.  XHTML is an XML form of HTML.

Comment: Beatiful soup uses HTMLParser/SGML<fill in blank, I forgot>

Answer (score 0):

See, for example, [extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python) for suggestions regarding ways for parsing HTML in Python.