# Malformed XML repair using python

Tags: python, xml

I have 50 XML files which has mismatched tags and I want to repair them using python. The opening tag `<names>` is different from closing tag `</name>`. Can anyone guide me please.

```
    <breakfast_menu>
      <food>
        <names>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <calories>650</calories>
     </food>
    </breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/399996/477878) may be of interest.

Comment: Why did you get such malformed xml files? Is it possible to fix the program that generates the xml?

Answer (score 6):

[`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) does this:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> myxml = # Your posted XML
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(myxml,'xml')
>>> print soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<names>Belgian Waffles</names>
<price>$5.95</price>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

If you were looking for `<name></name>`:

```
>>> for i in soup.findAll('names'):
...     i.name = 'name'
...
>>> print soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<breakfast_menu>
<food>
<name>Belgian Waffles</name>
<price>$5.95</price>
<calories>650</calories>
</food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: How do I change the opening tag same as closing tag and not the other way

Comment: BeautifulSoup can't do this directly when calling `BeautifulSoup`, but I have added in a way of doing so.

Comment: Thanks a lot let me try that out

Comment: also how do I open a XML in bs4 and then save it after modification.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. If you're talking about file input/output, then that's another question that can easily be searched upon on a search engine (or even this site itself)