# Convert Markdown tables to html tables using Python

Tags: python, html, markdown

I have a markdown table syntax string, say:

```
table_md=\
"| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |\n\
| ------------- |-------------| -----|\n\
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |\n\
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |\n\
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |\n"
```

I would like to convert it to html syntax table string:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Tables</th>
<th>Are</th>
<th>Cool</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>col 3 is</td>
<td>right-aligned</td>
<td>$1600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>col 2 is</td>
<td>centered</td>
<td>$12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>zebra stripes</td>
<td>are neat</td>
<td>$1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

First searching through stackoverflow, I have tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761824/python-how-to-convert-markdown-formatted-text-to-text):

```
import markdown
table_html=markdown.markdown(table_md)
```

But the result is a html paragraph:

```
'<p>| Tables...    |</p>'
```

By gooling the issue, I have come to [markdown extensions](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/index.html), and try add the extension to the command above:

```
table_html=markdown.markdown(table_md, extensions=[MyExtension(), \
'markdown.extensions.tables'])
```

Then it shows error saying that `"NameError: name 'MyExtension' is not defined"`

And there is no same situation in stackoverflow.

Please help me what to do with MyExtension above. Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort whatsoever was shown!

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I have added my efforts to the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

firstly you can have your input like below:

```
table_md="| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |\n\
| ------------- |-------------| -----|\n\
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |\n\
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |\n\
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |\n"
```

use an extension `markdown.extensions.tables`

```
table_html=markdown.markdown(table_md, extensions=['markdown.extensions.tables'])
```

Output is:

```
>>> print table_html
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Tables</th>
<th>Are</th>
<th>Cool</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>col 3 is</td>
<td>right-aligned</td>
<td>$1600</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>col 2 is</td>
<td>centered</td>
<td>$12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>zebra stripes</td>
<td>are neat</td>
<td>$1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you figured it out too :)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, the [extension library](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html#extensions) state that "The list of extensions may contain instances of extensions and/or strings of extension names", so MyExtension() is optional, so I can delete it in this case, the solution is:

```
table_html=markdown.markdown(table_md, extensions=['markdown.extensions.tables'])
```

For those who want to adding their own additions or changes to the syntax of Markdown, you can use MyExtension as follow:

```
from markdown.extensions import Extension
class MyExtension(Extension):
    # define your extension here...

markdown.markdown(text, extensions=[MyExtension(option='value')])
```