# Python : How to parse the Body from a raw email , given that raw email does not have a "Body" tag or anything

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

It seems easy to get the

```
From
To
Subject
```

etc via

```
import email
b = email.message_from_string(a)
bbb = b['from']
ccc = b['to']
```

assuming that `"a"` is the raw-email string which looks something like this.

```
a = """From root@a1.local.tld Thu Jul 25 19:28:59 2013
Received: from a1.local.tld (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4) with ESMTP id r6Q2SxeQ003866
    for <ooo@a1.local.tld>; Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by a1.local.tld (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6Q2Sxbh003865;
    Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700
From: root@a1.local.tld
Subject: oooooooooooooooo
To: ooo@a1.local.tld
Cc: 
X-Originating-IP: 192.168.15.127
X-Mailer: Webmin 1.420
Message-Id: <1374805739.3861@a1>
Date: Thu, 25 Jul 2013 19:28:59 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="bound1374805739"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--bound1374805739
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo

--bound1374805739--"""
```

**THE QUESTION**

how do you get the `Body` of this email via python ?

So far this is the only code i am aware of but i have yet to test it.

```
if email.is_multipart():
    for part in email.get_payload():
        print part.get_payload()
else:
    print email.get_payload()
```

is this the correct way ?

or maybe there is something simpler such as...

```
import email
b = email.message_from_string(a)
bbb = b['body']
```

?

Comment: Note that Python 3.6+ has convenience get_body() functions via upcoming default parsing policy, as noted in newer answer by @Doctor J, and note that answer by Todor Minakov is more robust that that by falsetru

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Use [Message.get_payload](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message#email.message.Message.get_payload)

```
b = email.message_from_string(a)
if b.is_multipart():
    for payload in b.get_payload():
        # if payload.is_multipart(): ...
        print payload.get_payload()
else:
    print b.get_payload()
```

Comment: Other answers do a better job of being more robust and leveraging the newer get_body() functionality.

Comment: @nealmcb, When I answered there was no `get_body` ;) Seems it appeared since Python 3.6. BTW, this question is tagged `python-2.7` where you can't use `get_body`

Comment: Good point! Of course with Python 2 now over a year past end-of-life, we can assume much more interest in modern solutions. But also note that as Todor describes, many emails have tricky structures, so a more general approach is a good idea, and your "..." is not very specific.

Answer (score 149):

To be highly positive you work with the actual email body (yet, still with the possibility you're not parsing the right part), you have to skip attachments, and focus on the plain or html part (depending on your needs) for further processing.

As the before-mentioned attachments can and very often are of text/plain or text/html part, this non-bullet-proof sample skips those by checking the content-disposition header:

```
b = email.message_from_string(a)
body = ""

if b.is_multipart():
    for part in b.walk():
        ctype = part.get_content_type()
        cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))

        # skip any text/plain (txt) attachments
        if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)  # decode
            break
# not multipart - i.e. plain text, no attachments, keeping fingers crossed
else:
    body = b.get_payload(decode=True)
```

BTW, `walk()` iterates marvelously on mime parts, and `get_payload(decode=True)` does the dirty work on decoding base64 etc. for you.

Some background - as I implied, the wonderful world of MIME emails presents a lot of pitfalls of "wrongly" finding the message body.
In the simplest case it's in the sole "text/plain" part and get_payload() is very tempting, but we don't live in a simple world - it's often surrounded in multipart/alternative, related, mixed etc. content. Wikipedia describes it tightly - [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), but considering all these cases below are valid - and common - one has to consider safety nets all around:

Very common - pretty much what you get in normal editor (Gmail,Outlook) sending formatted text with an attachment:

```
multipart/mixed
 |
 +- multipart/related
 |   |
 |   +- multipart/alternative
 |   |   |
 |   |   +- text/plain
 |   |   +- text/html
 |   |      
 |   +- image/png
 |
 +-- application/msexcel
```

Relatively simple - just alternative representation:

```
multipart/alternative
 |
 +- text/plain
 +- text/html
```

For good or bad, this structure is also valid:

```
multipart/alternative
 |
 +- text/plain
 +- multipart/related
      |
      +- text/html
      +- image/jpeg
```

P.S. My point is don't approach email lightly - it bites when you least expect it :)

Comment: Thanks for this thorough example and for spelling out a warning - in contrary to the accepted answer. I think this is a far better/safer approach.

Comment: Ah, very good! `.get_payload(decode=True)` instead of just `.get_payload()` has made life much easier, thanks!

Comment: I am looking for only the body from .get_payload(decode=True). Is there any way for it ?

Answer (score 19):

There is very good [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mail-parser) available to parse the email contents with proper documentation.

```
import mailparser

mail = mailparser.parse_from_file(f)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_file_obj(fp)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_string(raw_mail)
mail = mailparser.parse_from_bytes(byte_mail)
```

How to Use:

```
mail.attachments: list of all attachments
mail.body
mail.to
```

Comment: Library is great, but I had to make my own class that inherits from `MailParser` and override **body** method, because it joins the parts of email's body with **"\n--- mail_boundary ---\n"** which was not ideal for me.

Comment: hi @avram, could you please share the class that you have written ?

Comment: I managed to split the result on "\n--- mail_boundary ---\n".

Comment: @AmeyPNaik Here I made a quick github gist: https://gist.github.com/aleksaa01/ccd371869f3a3c7b3e47822d5d78ccdf

Comment: @AmeyPNaik in their [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mail-parser/), it says: _mail-parser can parse Outlook email format (.msg). To use this feature, you need to install libemail-outlook-message-perl package_

Answer (score 18):

Python 3.6+ provides built-in convenience methods to find and decode the plain text body as in `@Todor Minakov`'s answer.  You can use the [`EMailMessage.get_body()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.message.html?highlight=email#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body) and [`get_content()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_content) methods:

```
msg = email.message_from_string(s, policy=email.policy.default)
body = msg.get_body(('plain',))
if body:
    body = body.get_content()
print(body)
```

Note this will give `None` if there is no (obvious) plain text body part.

If you are reading from e.g. an mbox file, you can give the mailbox constructor an `EmailMessage` factory:

```
mbox = mailbox.mbox(mboxfile, factory=lambda f: email.message_from_binary_file(f, policy=email.policy.default), create=False)
for msg in mbox:
    ...
```

Note you must pass `email.policy.default` as the policy, since it's *not* the default...

Comment: Why isn't `email.policy.default` the default? Seems like it should be.

Comment: @PartialOrder Backwards compatibility. It *will* be the default, and you should already use it now.

Comment: This is very informative and encouraging, but had me confused for a while. The `lambda` doesn't reveal lack of import of "email.policy" right away, and I guess the factory is not consulted if you access a message explicitly, e.g. via `mbox.get_message(0)` Folks can note also the more explicit `make_EmailMessage` factory function approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57550079/507544

Comment: ```$ python -c 'import email, sys; msg = email.message_from_string(sys.stdin.read()); print(msg.get_body())' <<< some_text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'get_body'``` I got this error. Would you please let me know what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There is no `b['body']` in python. You have to use get_payload.

```
if isinstance(mailEntity.get_payload(), list):
    for eachPayload in mailEntity.get_payload():
        ...do things you want...
        ...real mail body is in eachPayload.get_payload()...
else:
    ...means there is only text/plain part....
    ...use mailEntity.get_payload() to get the body...
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If emails is the pandas dataframe and emails.message the column for email text

```
## Helper functions
def get_text_from_email(msg):
    '''To get the content from email objects'''
    parts = []
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            parts.append( part.get_payload() )
    return ''.join(parts)

def split_email_addresses(line):
    '''To separate multiple email addresses'''
    if line:
        addrs = line.split(',')
        addrs = frozenset(map(lambda x: x.strip(), addrs))
    else:
        addrs = None
    return addrs 

import email
# Parse the emails into a list email objects
messages = list(map(email.message_from_string, emails['message']))
emails.drop('message', axis=1, inplace=True)
# Get fields from parsed email objects
keys = messages[0].keys()
for key in keys:
    emails[key] = [doc[key] for doc in messages]
# Parse content from emails
emails['content'] = list(map(get_text_from_email, messages))
# Split multiple email addresses
emails['From'] = emails['From'].map(split_email_addresses)
emails['To'] = emails['To'].map(split_email_addresses)

# Extract the root of 'file' as 'user'
emails['user'] = emails['file'].map(lambda x:x.split('/')[0])
del messages

emails.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Small update based on Doctor J's answer. Parses the plaintext portion (if any) of the email message. May try getting the [html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body) as well since the (bad) habit of sending html only mails are increasingly popular.

```
from email import message_from_string
from email import policy

raw_string = raw_string.strip() # where raw_string is the email message (DATA)
msg = message_from_string(raw_string, policy=policy.default)
body = msg.get_body(('plain',))
if body:
    body = body.get_content()
    print(body)
```

When working with email DATA as strings, it's necessary to strip leading/trailing whitespace, wasted a lot of time without it!

Answer (score -3):

Here's the code that works for me everytime (for Outlook emails):

```
#to read Subjects and Body of email in a folder (or subfolder)

import win32com.client  
#import package

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")  
#create object

#get to the desired folder (MyEmail@xyz.com is my root folder)

root_folder = 
outlook.Folders['MyEmail@xyz.com'].Folders['Inbox'].Folders['SubFolderName']

#('Inbox' and 'SubFolderName' are the subfolders)

messages = root_folder.Items

for message in messages:
if message.Unread == True:    # gets only 'Unread' emails
    subject_content = message.subject
# to store subject lines of mails

    body_content = message.body
# to store Body of mails

    print(subject_content)
    print(body_content)

    message.Unread = True         # mark the mail as 'Read'
    message = messages.GetNext()  #iterate over mails
```

Comment: Perhaps spell out that this is for Outlook on Windows, not for real email.