# How to extract an email body from a file using email.Parser?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to use python and `email.Parser` to parse an email from a file. I use the following command

```
headers = Parser().parse(open(filename, 'r'))
```

to parse the file. But when I try to get the body I use e.g.

```
print(headers.get_payload()[0])
```

and I get something like

```
From nobody Mon Oct 12 16:32:25 2015
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Hi Alex,
....
```

Is there some way to get rid of those first three/four lines? And how to decode content like 'fr=C3=BCher'?

Answer (score 3):

To get to the message body, you have to walk() it's different parts, i.e.:

```
a = email.message_from_file(open(filename, 'r')) #shorthand for Parser().parse
body = ''

if a.is_multipart():
   for part in b.walk():
       ctype = part.get_content_type()
       cdispo = str(part.get('Content-Disposition'))

       # skip any text/plain (txt) attachments
       if ctype == 'text/plain' and 'attachment' not in cdispo:
           body = part.get_payload(decode=True)  # decode
           break
# not multipart - i.e. plain text, no attachments
else:
    body = b.get_payload(decode=True)
```

The decode=True in get_payload() does the base64/etc decoding, i.e the 'fr=C3=BCher' strings

Comment: sure thing; you can check a little longer rant by me on this topic, in the question Anurag has linked

Answer (score 0):

Use [Message.get_payload](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.get_payload)

Check this answer [Python : How to parse the Body from a raw email , given that raw email does not have a "Body" tag or anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874360/python-how-to-parse-the-body-from-a-raw-email-given-that-raw-email-does-not)