# Python Email body reading Getting Encoded data

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, email-parsing

While parsing the email content in python am getting the body as in some time of encoded format
Code

Please find the code Snippet:

```
str_list = list(filter(None, messages[0].decode().split(' ')))
print('No. of messages: {}'.format(len(str_list)))
if retcode == 'OK':
    for num in messages[0].decode().split(' '):
        if num:
            typ, data = conn.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
            for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    email_message = email.message_from_string(str(response_part[1]))
                    print(email_message)
```

Please find the Output below:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: xxxxx@yyyyyyy.com
To: xxxxx@yyyyyyy.com
Date: Thu,  1 Oct 2017 03:02:45 +0000
Subject: Check Mail
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Return-Path: xxxxx@yyyyyyy.com
Message-ID: <djfsdfjfio1212jio1@khapp>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 1 Oct 2017 03:02:43.0174 (UTC) FILETIME=    [79D8D860:01D49810]
X-SG-EID:     Ni9KCeztslc0dF3s9ZK0rLD1BsYqqLCIUtt6iPiL4/rTHVW4HL7/7rS9U/ajjnLrCeU2GpRoJKFiOj
qhYAgMrjliHtgoMwHAIe9awgq7fTf0pblztE2xpgfqQfwjbZuHbHl/ViWGYLmXrOoppzYzSAX4neAx
Tv4LdCXpVv5dS9GgzXk2jbBCXbhNhBs8VGEA7wgzj/NMA55SceW3xftiVw==
X-Feedback-ID:         5710108:5+HXwQH0vVQ/iziqTPdSABmkuAdLxfkHnhxScrL8ZIw=:5+HXwQH0vVQ/iziqTPdSABmkuAd    LxfkHnhxScrL8ZIw=:SG

PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWwgcHVibGljICItLy9XM0MvL0RURCBIVE1MIDQuMDEgVHJhbnNpdGlvbmFs
Ly9FTiI+Cgk8aHRtbD4KCQk8aGVhZD4NCiA8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PSJDb250ZW50LVR5cGUi
IGNvbnRlbnQ9InRleHQvaHRtbDtjaGFyc2V0PXdpbmRvd3MtMTI1MiI+DQogPHN0eWxlPg0KICAg
LyogRm9udCBEZWZpbml0aW9ucyAqLw0KICAgQGZvbnQtZmFjZQ0KIAkge2ZvbnQtZmFtaWx5OiJD
```

Is there anyway to decode this mail body content in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874360/python-how-to-parse-the-body-from-a-raw-email-given-that-raw-email-does-not

Comment: I had checked it... Still, it doesn't work