# In Python how to convert an `email.message.Message` object into an `email.message.EmailMessage` object

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, rfc822

From my understanding the `mbox` class in Python 3.6's standard library generates old-style message objects of the type `email.message.Message`.

The newer class `email.message.EmailMessage` introduced in 3.4/3.6 offers easier access to the content of the message (via `get_content()` and `get_body()`). How can I convert the `email.message.Message` objects I get from the `mbox` iterator  into `email.message.EmailMessage` objects?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question, but found a solution in the meantime. :) It’s possible to convert the old-style message to a string or bytes and parse it again using the [`email.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) module (the policy must be set to `email.policy.default`). But a more direct way would be to pass a factory to the `mbox` class. Like this: `mailbox.mbox(path, factory=lambda f: email.message_from_binary_file(f, policy=email.policy.default))`

Comment: @ManuelJacob That's so cool! Indeed using a factory is the best! Works perfectly. Worth while to be made into an answer, I reckon...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking [@ManuelJaco's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456080/in-python-how-to-convert-an-email-message-message-object-into-an-email-messag#comment101415754_57456080) I was able to create an `mbox` instance which contains  automatically message objects of the type `email.message.EmailMessage`:

```
def make_EmailMessage(f):
    """Factory to create EmailMessage objects instead of Message objects"""
    return email.message_from_binary_file(f, policy=email.policy.default)

mbox = mailbox.mbox(mboxfile, factory=make_EmailMessage)
```

Note: When iterating over `mbox` all messages (even messages contained in a message!) are of the `email.message.EmailMessage` type.

Answer (score 4):

To create an `email.message.EmailMessage` object, change the policy in parser to `email.policy.default`.

```
msg = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string,
                            policy = email.policy.default)
```