# Use regex to extract recepient and sender from an email text in python

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions and am getting pretty frustrated with this. I have the following text:

```
From: sender name
To: the recepient
Subject: well done!
Body: lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

I am trying to extract the text in the lines "From" and "To". I wrote the following regex:

`(^From: [a-zA-Z]*)+|(^To: [a-zA-Z]*)+|(^Subject: [a-zA-Z])+`

and I'm matching it using this code:

```
regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
result = regex.match(text).groups()
```

but this is only matching the first line. I couldn't figure out what's wrong nor do I seem to understand how to write regular expressions correctly

Comment: Why not like just like `^(From: .*)\n(To: .*)` with 2 capture groups separated by a newline? See https://ideone.com/jxtFXs

Comment: Use `regex.finditer` or `regex.findall`

Comment: See [Python : How to parse the Body from a raw email , given that raw email does not have a "Body" tag or anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874360/) and [this demo](https://ideone.com/Sq3k5e).

Comment: The mentioned duplicate is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to stay close to your approach, the pattern `^From: ([ a-zA-Z]*)\nTo: ([ a-zA-Z]*)` results in:

```py
>>> result
('sender name', 'the recepient')
```

Now, why doesn't your pattern work?

1. `(^From: [a-zA-Z]*)` would never capture `sender name` because you're not allowing any whitespace with `[a-zA-Z]`
2. Using the `A|B` pattern makes it so the engine matches either `A` OR `B`, so it wouldn't look for your `To:` pattern after encountering `From:`

Answer (score 1):

You are using an alternation `|` which matches one of the alternatives using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

Also the character classes `[a-zA-Z]*` are optional and not matching spaces and `[a-zA-Z]` only matches a single character.

You can use 2 capture groups with a newline in between, and match `From:` and `To:` followed by the rest of the line.

```
import re

text = ("From: sender name\n"
            "To: the recepient\n"
            "Subject: well done!\n"
            "Body: lorem ipsum lorem ipsum")
regex = re.compile(r"^(From: .*)\n(To: .*)", flags=re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
print(regex.match(text).groups())
```

Output

```
('From: sender name', 'To: the recepient')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex needs some work and there are multiple ways to get results, but if you're going to structure your regex in a similar way using the or character "|", then here is a good start for you:

```
import re

example_text = """
From: sender name
To: the recepient
Subject: well done!
Body: lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
"""

pattern = re.compile(r'^From: (.+)|^To: (.+)|^Subject: (.+)', re.MULTILINE)
for match in pattern.finditer(example_text):
    print(match.group())
```

This will output:

```
From: sender name
To: the recepient
Subject: well done!
```

But you need to get an idea of expected input. Will there be spaces? What if there is no subject? I'll leave it to you to figure out what's best.