# How to get the text of the email body?

Tags: python, email, mime

I have this code but I don't actually get the email text.

Have I got to decode the email text?

```
import sys
import imaplib
import getpass
import email
import email.header
from email.header import decode_header
import base64

def read(username, password, sender_of_interest):
    # Login to INBOX
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.mail.com", 993)
    imap.login(username, password)
    imap.select('INBOX')
    # Use search(), not status()
    # Print all unread messages from a certain sender of interest
    if sender_of_interest:
        status, response = imap.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN', 'FROM {0}'.format(sender_of_interest))
    else:
        status, response = imap.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')
    if status == 'OK':
        unread_msg_nums = response[0].split()
    else:
        unread_msg_nums = []
    data_list = []
    for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
        data_dict = {}
        e_id = e_id.decode('utf-8')
        _, response = imap.uid('fetch', e_id, '(RFC822)')
        html = response[0][1].decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(html)
        data_dict['mail_to'] = email_message['To']
        data_dict['mail_subject'] = email_message['Subject']
        data_dict['mail_from'] = email.utils.parseaddr(email_message['From'])
        #data_dict['body'] = email_message.get_payload()[0].get_payload()
        data_dict['body'] = email_message.get_payload()
        data_list.append(data_dict)
    print(data_list)
    # Mark them as seen
    #for e_id in unread_msg_nums:
        #imap.store(e_id, '+FLAGS', '\Seen')
    imap.logout()    
    return data_dict
```

So I do this:

```
print('Getting the email text bodiies ... ')
emailData = read(usermail, pw, sender_of_interest)
print('Got the data!')
for key in emailData.keys():
    print(key, emailData[key])
```

The output is:

> mail_to me@mail.com
> mail_subject Get json file
> mail_from ('Pedro Rodriguez', 'pedro@gmail.com')
> body [<email.message.Message object at 0x7f7d9f928df0>, <email.message.Message object at 0x7f7d9f928f70>]

How to actually get the email text?

Comment: This might be of help, within the email class their is a message method which has a function called as_string( ) which flattens the whole message into a string. I haven't ever approached this but i'll leave the docs here

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html

Comment: did you try to rtfm: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html ?

Comment: I rolled back your edits. You asked how to get "the body" and you accepted the answer which tells you how to do that. Ask a new question if you now have another problem you want to solve (but please search before asking; this topic is well-covered in existing question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python : How to parse the Body from a raw email , given that raw email does not have a "Body" tag or anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874360/python-how-to-parse-the-body-from-a-raw-email-given-that-raw-email-does-not)

Comment: Thanks for your link. I made a function to get the attachment(s), seems to work ok. So now I have functions for getting everything. Not that I need to do this a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you mean by "the text", you probably want the [`get_body` method.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body) But you are thoroughly mangling the email before you get to that point. What you receive from the server isn't "HTML" and converting it to a string to then call `message_from_string` on it is roundabout and error-prone. What you get are bytes; use the `message_from_bytes` method directly. (This avoids all kinds of problems when the bytes are not UTF-8; the `message_from_string` method only really made sense back in Python 2, which didn't have explicit `bytes`.)

```
from email.policy import default
...

        _, response = imap.uid(
            'fetch', e_id, '(RFC822)')
        email_message = email.message_from_bytes(
            response[0][1], policy=default)
        body = email_message.get_body(
            ('html', 'text')).get_content()
```

The use of a `policy` selects the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage`; you need Python 3.3+ for this to be available. The older legacy `email.Message` class did not have this method, but should be avoided in new code for many other reasons as well.

This could fail for multipart messages with nontrivial nested structures; the `get_body` method without arguments can return a `multipart/alternative` message part and then you have to take it from there. You haven't specified what your messages are expected to look like so I won't delve further into that.

More fundamentally, you probably need a more nuanced picture of how modern email messages are structured. See [What are the "parts" in a multipart email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48562935/what-are-the-parts-in-a-multipart-email)

Comment: I added a second pair of parentheses around the `get_body` arguments; sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve the problem: I get this for body: 'body': b'<div dir="ltr">Can you get the attachment?</div>\r\n'}] Still seems to be bytes, but I can get that to a string, I think!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, I got this for the email body.

> <email.message.Message object at 0x7f7d9f928df0>

I didn't know it, but that is all you need! I didn't know what to do with it! I suppose, when you have done this a few times, you know this and it is easy!

You can get the above in 2 ways, whereby 1 seems directer:

1.

```
status, messageParts = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
email_message = email.message_from_bytes(messageParts[0][1], policy=default)
```

gives:
email_message

> <email.message.EmailMessage object at 0x7fae30730ca0>

2. status, messageParts = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
   emailBody = messageParts[0][1]
   raw_email_string = emailBody.decode('utf-8')

   ## this below makes msg = <email.message.Message object at 0x7fae31758af0>

   ## you can get this from directly email_message = email.message_from_bytes(messageParts[0][1], policy=default)

   ```
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
   ```

   gives:
   email_message

> <email.message.EmailMessage object at 0x7fae30730ca0>

Either way, you want email_message as an email module  email.message.EmailMessage object which is walkable.
You can get all the info you want!

```
email_message['To']
'me@mail.com'
email_message['From']
'Pedro Rodriguez <me@gmail.com>'
email_message['Date']
'Sun, 25 Feb 2024 16:55:55 +0100'
```

To get the plain body text:

```
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
        print(part.get_payload())
```

> Here is the report you wanted.

To get html text:

```
for part in email_message.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == "text/html":
        print(part.get_payload())
```

> Here is the report you wanted.

And if you want to get an attached json file:

```
# get attached json file
            if part.get_content_type() == "application/json":
                filename = part.get_filename()
                if filename:
                    filePath = os.path.join(savepath, 'email_attachments', filename)
                    with open(filePath, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                        print(f"Saved TLS-RPT report: {filePath}")
```