# Parsing the HTML content in email

Tags: python, email, parsing, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to write a python script to read my emails.
I'm able to get most of the things properly like `To`, `From`, `Subject`.
But in the `body`, I get the text as well as it's HTML code too as shown below.

[image]

Below is the part of code that does the extraction of content from the email

```
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email)
print 'To:', email_message['To']
print 'Sent from:', email_message['From']
print 'Date:', email_message['Date']
print 'Subject:', email_message['Subject']
print '*'*30, 'MESSAGE', '*'*30
maintype = email_message.get_content_maintype()
#print maintype

if maintype == 'multipart':
    for part in email_message.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                print part.get_payload()
elif maintype == 'text':
    print email_message.get_payload()
print '*'*69
```

Git link for the complete code: [Email-parser](https://github.com/ab-anand/Python-works/blob/master/new.py)

How to get rid of that HTML code and get only the plain text?

Comment: so whats your problem?!

Comment: @DRPK Sorry I forgot to mention. Editted now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of the message is MIME-encoded - that's why it contains the text in both plaintext and HTML formats.  In order to get just the plaintext of the body, you first need to MIME-decode the message.  You can use python's [email package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email) to do the MIME-decoding.  Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449220/how-do-i-recieve-a-html-email-as-a-regular-text) for more information.