# Extract text from HTML in python

Tags: python, html, text, extract, web-crawler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

What is the best way in Python to extract text from HTML pages in the same way that browser does when you copy-paste?

Comment: possible duplicate. I recommend this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3987802/117092

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular option for reading and parsing HTML pages.

Comment: Dang. What easy points, @Makoto!  `:D`

Answer (score 2):

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python) that [monkut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24718/monkut) references doesn't give any Python solution to the exact problem.  While [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and lxml both can be used to parse html, there is still a big step from there to text that approximates the formatting that is embedded in the html.

To do this, I have resorted to non-python solutions (which I've blogged about, but will resist linking here-- not sure of the SO etiquette). If you are on a *nix system, you can install [this html2text package](http://www.mbayer.de/html2text/files.shtml) from Germany.  It can be installed easily on a MacOS with Homebrew (`$ brew install html2text`) or Macports (`$ sudo port install html2text`), and on other *nix systems through their package managers.  It has a number of useful options, and I use it like this:

`html2text -nobs -ascii -width 200 -style pretty -o filename.txt - < filename.html`

You can also install a text-based browser (e.g. [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/)) and use it to produce formatted text from html using the following command-line syntax:
`w3m filename.html -dump > file.txt`

You can, of course, access these solutions from Python using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module or the popular [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) wrapper for `subprocess`.

Even after all this effort, you may find that some important information (e.g. `<u>` tags) are not handled in a way you like, but those are the best current options that I have found.