# html-to-text conversion using Python standard library only

Tags: python, html-parsing, standard-library, html-to-text

I'm looking for the best way to convert HTML to text, using only modules from the Python 2.7.x standard library.  (I.e., no `BeautifulSoup`, etc.)

By HTML-to-text conversion I mean the moral equivalent of `lynx -dump`.  In fact, just getting rid of HTML tags intelligently, and converting all HTML-entities to ASCII (or to UTF8-encoded unicode), would suffice.

No regex-based answers, please.  (Regexes are not up to the task.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python since 2.2 has [**HTMLParser module**](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html). It's not the most efficient nor the easiest use, but it's there...

And if you're dealing with proper XHTML (or you can pass it through Tidy), you can use much better [**ElementTree**](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("your_document.xhtml")
your_string = tree.tostring(method="text", encoding="utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a really simple python script that extracts headings and paragraphs only from HTML files without using any third-party 
Libraries.
Note: This script is really simple and can only handle really simple HTML.
And its written in python 3

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
#This is a standard python module
headings = "<h1>"
paragraphs = "<p>"



f = open('filename.html')
f.close

for line in f: 
   if headings in line:
      print ("line")
   If paragraphs in line:
     print ("line")
```

You can still expand on this idea and make it extract more stuff from the HTML file.

Comment: Have you even tried this code? I think it's unfair to even call it code.

Answer (score -1):

I would also suggest that you should take a look at [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/). 
Also take a look at another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Comment: i specifically asked for answers that required only modules in the standard python distribution; html2text is not in the standard library