# Bash/Python : open url & print top 10 words

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I need to extract the 10 most frequent words from a text using a pipe (and any additional python scripts as needed); output being a block of all-caps words separated by a space. 
This pipe needs to extract text from any external file: I've managed to get it to work on .txt files, but I also need to be able to input a URL and have it do the same thing with that.

I have the following code:

```
alias words="tr a-zA-Z | tr -cs A-Z | tr ' ' '\012' | sort -n | uniq -c | 
sort -r | head -n 10 | awk '{printf \"%s \", \$2}END{print \"\"}'" (on one line)
```

which, with `cat hamlet.txt | words` gives me:

```
TO THE AND A  'TIS THAT OR OF IS
```

To make it more complicated, I need to exclude any 'function' words: these are 'non-lexical' words like 'a', 'the', 'of', 'is', any pronouns (I, you, him), and any prepositions (there, at, from).

I need to be able to type `htmlstrip http://www.google.com.au | words` and have it print out like the above.

For the URL-opening:
The python script I'm trying to figure out (let's call it htmlstrip) strips any tags from the text, leaving only 'human readable' text. This *should* be able to open any given URL, but I can't figure out how to get this to work. 
What I have so far:

```
import re
import urllib2
filename = raw_input('File name: ')
filehandle = open(filename)
html = filehandle.read()

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://') #???
print f.read()

text = [ ]
inTag = False


for ch in html:
    if ch == '<':
        inTag = True
    if not inTag:
        text.append(ch)
    if ch == '>':
        inTag = False

print ''.join(text)
```

I know this is both incomplete and probably incorrect - any guidance would really be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably be looking at BeautifulSoup for how to download a HTML page and strip it down to human-readable; http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/. This is a FAQ; see also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753052/strip-html-from-strings-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python

Comment: ... or if you are not particularly into using Python for this, `lynx -dump http://page.example.com/ | words`

Comment: :( unfortunately, for this particular task I need to use Python, with no external modules. I'll have a look @ the other posts though, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [scrape.py](http://zesty.ca/scrape/) and regular expressions like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from scrape import s
import sys, re

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "Usage: words.py url"
    sys.exit(0)

s.go(sys.argv[1]) # fetch content
text = s.doc.text # extract readable text
text = re.sub("\W+", " ", text) # remove all non-word characters and repeating whitespace
print text
```

And then just:
`./words.py http://whatever.com`

Comment: You can replace everything below `text=s.doc.text` with one line: `text = re.sub("\W+", " ", text)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` for this:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r"<.+>", " ", html)
```

For special cases such as scripts, you can include a regex such as:

```
<script.*>.*</script>
```

Comment: won't remove inline css and javascript

Comment: @Jeff: No, it won't. I agree with triplee that the best approach here is to use an actual html parser. Apparently the OP doesn't want to use any "external modules", however.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Sorry, just read the comment about the pure Python without any additional modules. Yes, in this situation `re`, I think, will be the best way.

Maybe it'll be easier and more correct to use `pycURL` rather then to remove tags by `re`?

```
from StringIO import StringIO    
import pycurl

url = 'http://www.google.com/'

storage = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, storage.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
content = storage.getvalue()
print content
```