# How to parse the xml file in the google-blogger in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an [xml file](http://s.yunio.com/bmCS5h).
It is the list of my files in Google-blogger, how can I parse it in python to get every article?please give me the right code,which can get exact result.

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('blog.xml')
for entry in d.entries:
    print entry.content[0]['value']
```

I get all my articles in google-blogger,but the format of the file is mess,can i get only woeds ,to delete the  html labels in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an [Atom feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(standard)); use [feedparser](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) to parse that file into individual articles.

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse('/path/to/your/xmlfile.xml')
for entry in d.entries:
    print entry.title
```

This prints:

```
模板: R
为此博客设置的发布类型。
此博客管理员的电子邮件列表。
此博客是否包含成人内容
是否允许使用备用的 JS 渲染
博客的 Google Analytics（分析）帐号
存档索引日期格式的编号
此博客的存档频率应该为多少
有权进行发布的作者的电子邮件列表。
是否在博客中显示评论反向链接
是否为每个帖子提供存档页
哪些人能发表评论
是否要求评论者完成 Captcha
用于接收新评论通知的电子邮件地址列表
为博客评论所提供的 Feed 类型
博客评论表位置
博客评论消息
是否启用评论审阅
新评论进行审阅的天数
用于接收需要审阅新评论的通知的电子邮件地址
```

etc.

You can see what items each entry defines by looking at the result of the `.keys()` method:

```
>>> d.entries[0].keys()
['updated', u'gd_image', 'updated_parsed', 'published_parsed', 'tags', 'title', 'links', 'summary', 'content', 'guidislink', 'title_detail', 'link', 'author', 'published', 'authors', 'author_detail', 'id']
```

If you want to convert your HTML content to text, there are a few options. Most are listed in: 
 [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Comment: i get `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'title'`

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: It turns out there was a typo in the example. Do read the `feedparser` documentation though.

Comment: how can i get the content?

Comment: You are looking for `entry.content`.

Comment: `print entry.content[0]['value']` can make me get the content,but how can i get a more better ,easy-readable formatted  content?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature: You could convert the HTML content to text: [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/328356)