# How to get pure text from a string in python?

Tags: python

There is a string with many html labels  in it such as the following,
`u'find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp; -name "[0-9]*"<br />find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp; -name "[!0-9]*"<br />find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp; -name "[^0-9]*"<br /><br />\u627e\u51fa\u6240\u6709\u5305\u542b\u6570\u5b57\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\uff0c\u4e0d\u5305\u542b\u6570\u5b57\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u3002<br />tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp; -name "*[0-9]*"&nbsp; &gt;kan1<br />tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp; -name "[0-9]*"&nbsp; &gt;kan2<br />tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp; -name "*[0-9]"&nbsp; &gt;kan3<br /><br /><br />\u5305\u542b\u6570\u5b57\uff0c\u6570\u5b57\u5f00\u5934\uff0c\u6570\u5b57\u7ed3\u5c3e'`

How can i get the pure text in the string to delete html labels ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text) library:

```
>>> print html2text.html2text(s)
find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp_place_holder; -name "[0-9]*"

find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp_place_holder; -name "[!0-9]*"

find /home/tiger/workspace&nbsp_place_holder; -name "[^0-9]*"


找出所有包含数字的文件，不包含数字的文件。

tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp_place_holder; -name
"*[0-9]*"&nbsp_place_holder; >kan1

tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp_place_holder; -name
"[0-9]*"&nbsp_place_holder; >kan2

tiger@debian:~$ find /home/tiger&nbsp_place_holder; -name
"*[0-9]"&nbsp_place_holder; >kan3



包含数字，数字开头，数字结尾
```

See [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python) for reference.