# Trouble Getting a clean text file from HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have looked at [these previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

I am trying to consolidate news and notes from websites.

Reputed News service websites allow Users to post comments and views.

I am trying to get only the news content without the users comments. I tried working with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/). But user-comments are being included in the text file. I have even tried developing a custom program but with no useful progress than the above two.

Can anybody provide some clue how to proceed?

**The code:**

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL ='http://www.example.com'
print 'Following: ',URL
print "Loading..."
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
identify_as = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
print "Reading URL:"+str(URL)    
def process(URL,identify_as):
    req = urllib2.Request(URL,data=None,headers=identify_as)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
    _BSobj = BeautifulSoup(response).prettify(encoding='utf-8')
    return _BSobj #return beauifulsoup object
print 'Processing URL...'
new_string = process(URL,identify_as).split()

print 'Buidiing requested Text'
tagB = ['<title>','<p>']    
tagC = ['</title>','</p>']
reqText = []
for num in xrange(len(new_string)):
    buffText = [] #initialize and reset
    if new_string[num] in tagB: 
        tag = tagB.index(new_string[num])
        while new_string[num] != tagC[tag]:
            buffText.append(new_string[num])
            num+=1
        reqText.extend(buffText)


reqText= ''.join(reqText)
fileID = open('reqText.txt','w')
fileID.write(reqText)
fileID.close()
```

Comment: You'd better give us some samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example I wrote using urllib which gets the contents of a page to a file:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
myurl = "http://www.mysite.com"

sock = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl)
pagedata = str(sock.read())                          
sock.close()

file = open("output.txt","w")
file.write(pagedata)
file.close()
```

Then with a lot of string formatting you should be able to extract the parts of the html you want. This gives you something to get started from.