# Python, get text value of an html document

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question is very simple, i have a string that contains html tags 
and i just want to get the actual text value from that string, example:

html string:

```
<strong><p> hello </p><p> world </p></strong>
```

text value: hello world

Is there a function that can do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)'s `get_text()` function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


text = "<strong><p> hello </p><p> world </p></strong>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
print soup.get_text()  # prints " hello  world "
```

Or, you can use [nltk](http://nltk.org/):

```
import nltk


text = "<strong><p> hello </p><p> world </p></strong>"
print nltk.clean_html(text)  # prints "hello world"
```

Another option is to use [html2text](https://github.com/aaronsw/html2text), but it behaves a bit defferently: e.g. `strong` is replaced with `*`.

Also see relevant thread: [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks BeautifulSoup's function works good but one more question when i try to print the resulted text it gives me this error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 47: ordinal not in range(128) , ps: i'm working with french text that contains accents

Comment: don't bother i found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20