# How can I extract data from a html tag using Python?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the translation of a word in online dictionary.
For example, the html code for 'car':

```
<ol class="sense_list level_1">
     <li class="sense_list_item level_1" value="1"><span class="def">any vehicle on wheels</span></li>
```

How can I extract "any vehicle on wheels" in Python with [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or any other modules?

Comment: thanks for all answers. but that html code has other lines similar to above line with only one difference: value="1" .for each line value changes. how can i extract line with value="1"

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python

Comment: I have modified my answer to include start tag and attributes.

Comment: @SaraSantana updated the answer - the last option checks for the `value` attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by beautifulsoup:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
q1=soup.find('li', class_="sense_list_item level_1",value='1').text
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to reach the desired element.

Probably the simplest would be to find it by `class`:

```
soup.find('span', class_='def').text
```

or, with a `CSS selector`:

```
soup.select('span.def')[0].text
```

or, additionally checking the parents:

```
soup.select('ol.level_1 > li.level_1 > span.def')[0].text
```

or:

```
soup.select('ol.level_1 > li[value=1] > span.def')[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is the only HTML code given, you can use [NLTK](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nltk).

```
import nltk 

#load html chunk into variable htmlstring#
extract = nltk.clean_html(htmlstring)
print(extract)
```