# Optimal way to find element containing`data-superid="picture-link"?

Tags: python, selenium

The element I'm looking to find looks like this:

`<a href="pic:/82eu92e/iwjd/" data-superid="picture-link">`

Previously I found all href's in the page, then found the correct href by finding which one had the text `pic:`, but I can't do this any longer due to some pages having scrolling galleries causing stale elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by attribute:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-superid="picture-link"]')
```

Regarding the scrolling part, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391303/how-to-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-page-using-selenium-in-python/32629481) is a previously asked question that can help you.

Comment: By the way I can scroll pages fine! I meant there was a gallery scrolling left/right automatically that would cause stale elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `beautifulsoup + selenium`, like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''<a href="pic:/82eu92e/iwjd/" data-superid="picture-link">'''
# Under your circumstance, you need to use:
# text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("a", attrs={"data-superid":"picture-link"}))
```

Result:

```
<a data-superid="picture-link" href="pic:/82eu92e/iwjd/"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried but it returned `None`, probably due to me tampering it to make the pic value a wildcard. Got it working through other method.

Answer (score 0):

To Extract the `href` value using `data-superid="picture-link"` use following css selector or xpath.

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[data-superid='picture-link'][href]")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

OR

```
links=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-superid='picture-link'][@href]")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```