# Extracting paragraphs from a gobble of html

Tags: regex, parsing, nltk

How can I extract relevant information from the gobble of words I got from these gobble of html:

```
><br>Inspect, diagnose, maintain, and operate test setups and equipment to detect malfunctions.\n<br><br>Record and interpret test data on parts, assemblies, and mechanisms.\n<br><br>Confer with engineering personnel regarding details and implications of test procedures and results.\n<br><br>Adjust, repair or replace faulty components of test setups and equipment.\n<br><br>Identify required data, data acquisition plans and test parameters, setting up equipment to conform to these specifications.\n<br></p><br><br><b>Key Skills:</b><p class=\'indented\'><br>Critical Thinking - Using logic and reasoning to identify the strengths and weaknesses of alternative solutions, conclusions or approaches to problems.<br><br>Active Listening - Giving full attention to what other people are saying, taking time to understand the points being made, asking questions as appropriate, and not interrupting at inappropriate times.<br><br>Speaking - Talking to others to convey information effectively.<br><br>Operation Monitoring - Watching gauges, dials, or other indicators to make sure a machine is working properly.<br><br>Reading Comprehension - Understanding written sentences and paragraphs in work related documents.<br><br>Quality Control Analysis - Conducting tests and inspections of products, services, or processes to evaluate quality or performance.<br><br>Complex Problem Solving - Identifying complex problems and reviewing related information to develop and evaluate options and implement solutions.<br><br>Monitoring - Monitoring/Assessing performance of yourself, other individuals, or organizations to make improvements or take corrective action.<br><br>Judgment and Decision Making - Considering the relative costs and benefits of potential actions to choose the most appropriate one.<br><br>Time Management - Managing one\'s own time and the time of others.<br></p>
```

Comment: You will need to provide more information, specifically *what* information you are after, *what* have you tried and *what* you are getting.

Comment: Only the natural language/common words. The above is just a snippet of a series of html codes. It appears that the paragraph that I want to extract is concentrated in one block of the html code and I want ignore all the unnecessary language alongside the html.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python) question probably does what you are after.