# how to remove number, dot and alphabets bullets from list while extracting text from website:

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python 2.7.8. I have a website which contains text written with bullets list which is ordered list aka <**ol**> . I want to extract those text i.e

```
Coffee
Tea
Milk
```

My html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ol type="I">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
<ol type="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

The code which is i am constantly trying is not working bcz on the way i am every time getting Error.

Python code:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/"
#url="http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-2/"
req = Request(url)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
htmls = resp.read()
c=0;
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'lxml')
#skipp portion of code
res2 = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"entry-title"})
br = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'IL_ADS'})
br = soup.find('p').text # separate title

for question in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"^\d+\.")):
    answers = [br.next_sibling.strip() for br in question.find_next_siblings("br")]
    #s = ''.join([i for i in question if not i.isdigit()])
    if not answers:
        break

    print question.encode('utf-8')
    ul = question.find_next_sibling("ul")
    print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))
```

but when i run this code i got also Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\fyp\crawldataextraction.py", line 47, in <module>
    print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Comment: Do you want to extract the text within the <li> tags or attribute "type" within tag <ol>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Comment: The tags you're searching is `ul` in your code, but I can only see `ol` tags in your HTML file. Isn't this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see why it is that beautifulsoup function does not work for your variable 'ul" by inserting this line while commenting out the line you previously had.

```
print ul
"""print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))"""
```

What is happening is that your variable ul is storing the string:

1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.
   None
2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.
   None
3. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
   None
4. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
   None
5. Variable names beginning with underscore is not encouraged. Why?
   None
6. All keywords in C are in
   None
7. Variable name resolving (number of significant characters for uniqueness of variable) depends on
   None
8. Which of the following is not a valid C variable name?
   None
9. Which of the following is true for variable names in C?
   None

   ### But since there is no ul tag for beautifulsoup to find inside of ul, your ul.get_text method does not work. So in this case, the way I would go about stripping the spaces would be to use regex.

Answer about removing number and dots.

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import Request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/"
#url="http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-2/"
req = Request(url)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
htmls = resp.read()
c = 0
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'lxml')
# skipp portion of code
res2 = soup.find('h1', attrs={"class": "entry-title"})
br = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'IL_ADS'})
br = soup.find('p').text  # separate title

for question in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"^\d+\.")):
    answers = [br.next_sibling.strip() for br in question.find_next_siblings("br")]
    # s = ''.join([i for i in question if not i.isdigit()])
    if not answers:
        break
    ul = question.encode('utf-8')
    ol = re.compile('[\d][.]')
    ol = ol.sub(' ', str(ul))
    print ol
    """print(ul.get_text(' ', strip=True))"""
```

Output:

```
  C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.
  C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.
  Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
  Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
  Variable names beginning with underscore is not encouraged. Why?
  All keywords in C are in
  Variable name resolving (number of significant characters for uniqueness of variable) depends on
  Which of the following is not a valid C variable name?
  Which of the following is true for variable names in C?
```

I used regex to compile the pattern of number followed by a dot. Then used the re.sub() function to replace it with a space.

Comment: thanks Calcus for close response. But how shall i remove those numbers i thought it is ul or ol ??Your sol is printing None....

Comment: or example if i want to remove: 1. ________ 2.________ i can also use str.replace("1.","") but this becomes lengthy for me as i ve write upto infinte times. Likewise for: a) ________ b) ________ str.replace("a)","") same here –

Comment: For the first question, in your case it doesn't seem to matter with using ul or ol as beautifulsoup is picking up the same string (the questions) with either one. Though you should note that ol stands for ordered list (applicable in your case) while ul stands for unordered list.

Comment: For the second, I would recommend looking through the regex documentation and especially re.sub()

Comment: I've updated my answer to show regex in action where it prints out the questions without the number followed by a dot.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the BeautifulSoup, but I do this with regular expression:

```
import re

html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ol type="I">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
<ol type="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ol type="1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>"""

regexp = re.compile('<li>(\w+)<\/li>')
result = regexp.findall(html)

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

Comment: my regex "compile(r"^\d+\.")" is also necessary for me. And if i do
compile(r"<li>^\d+<\/li>.") gets nothing

Comment: You need use group to get things. You have try use `<li>(^\d+)<\/li>`? You could use this site to test your regexp: https://regex101.com/

Comment: for example if i want to remove:
1. ________
2.________ 

i can also use str.replace("1.","") but this becomes lengthy for me as i ve write upto infinte times. Likewise for:
a) ________
b) ________
str.replace("a)","") same here