# How to extract the name out of this html with regex

Tags: regex

```
<a rel="profile-edit" class="app js-user-name" href="/profile/0471482493?from_my_profile=1">Mia</a></b>   <
```

Hello I have a variable defined with the above text can someone please tell me the regex that would be required to extract jst the word "Mia" from the html? The word will not always be Mia.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please try to use a search prior to asking a question. Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Comment: A simple one can be `/([A-Z])\w+/g` and a safer one can be `/\w+(?=<)/`

Comment: Thanks, I searched a bit but not enough I will check it out. :)

Comment: Nope neither worked, why are people down voting my question?

Comment: @Matt Do you have to take regex?
You can get the word with javascript. `innerHTML`

Comment: Hey, no actually I don't have to use regex. I am working on a ubot which allows js functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
/>.*?([^<]+)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dZ4dF9/1)

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your post, I tried it to no avail. This may be a ubot issue.