# Remove HTML block in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'd like to know if there's a library or some method in Python to extract an element from an HTML document. For example:

I have this document:

```html
<html>
      <head>
          ...
      </head>
      <body>
          <div>
           ...
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

I want to remove the `<div></div>` tag block along with the block contents from the document and then it'll be like that:

```html
<html>
    <head>
     ...
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove only the `<div></div>` tags or both the tags & the contents inside those?

Comment: I want to remove the tags and the content between them. But only the content is ok as well :)

Comment: You can try reading the html file as xml and removing the `div` node. https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml suggests using *ElementTree*

Comment: But the most important for me it's removing the content @SimonHänisch

Comment: removing the node includes removing the content of the node

Comment: Ok. Thank guys. I know what I have to do now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a library for this. Just use built in string methods.

```
def removeOneTag(text, tag):
    return text[:text.find("<"+tag+">")] + text[text.find("</"+tag+">") + len(tag)+3:]
```

This will remove everything in-between the first opening and closing tag. So your input in the example would be something like...

```
    x = """<html>
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
       <div>
         ...
       </div>
    </body>
</html>"""
print(removeOneTag(x, "div"))
```

Then if you wanted to remove ALL the tags...

```
while(tag in x):
    x = removeOneTag(x, tag)
```

Comment: Cool. I really wouldn't need a lib. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally feel that you don't need a library or something.

You can simply write a python script to read the html file and a regex to match your desired html tags and then do whatever you want to with it (delete in your case)

Though, there exist a library for the same.

See the official documentation -> https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Also see this -> [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Answer (score -2):

Try using a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to select the `<div>` DOM element. Then you can remove it using regex or similar.