# How do I write web-scraped text into csv using python?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been working on a practice web-scraper that gets written reviews and writes them to a csv file, with each review given its own row. I've been having trouble with it as:

1. I can't seem to **strip out the html** and get only the text (i.e. the written review and nothing else)
2. There are a lot of **weird spaces between and within even my review text** (i.e. a row of space between lines etc.)

Thanks for your help!

Code below:

```
#! python3

import bs4, os, requests, csv

# Get URL of the page

URL = ('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294265-d2149128-Reviews-Gardens_by_the_Bay-Singapore.html')

# Looping until the 5th page of reviews

pagecounter = 0
while pagecounter != 5:

    # Request get the first page
    res = requests.get(URL)
    res.raise_for_status

    # Download the html of the first page
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    reviewElems = soup.select('.partial_entry')


    if reviewElems == []:
        print('Could not find clue.')

    else:
        #for i in range(len(reviewElems)):
            #print(reviewElems[i].getText())

        with open('GardensbytheBay.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:

            for row in reviewElems:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
                writer.writerow(row)
            print('Writing page')

    # Find URL of next page and update URL
    if pagecounter == 0:
        nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[0]

    elif pagecounter != 0:
        nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[1]

    URL = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com' + nextLink.get('href')
    pagecounter += 1

print('Download complete')
csvfile.close()
```

Comment: 2) browsers don't care of spaces when they display HTML so people (creating webpages) don't care of spaces too. They (or its functions) add spaces to make it more readable during developning - browsers will skip this spaces when they display HTML.

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python#8201491.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row.get_text(strip=True)` to get the text from your selected `p.partial_entry`. Try the following:

```
import bs4, os, requests, csv

# Get URL of the page
URL = ('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g294265-d2149128-Reviews-Gardens_by_the_Bay-Singapore.html')

with open('GardensbytheBay.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ')

    # Looping until the 5th page of reviews
    for pagecounter in range(6):

        # Request get the first page
        res = requests.get(URL)
        res.raise_for_status

        # Download the html of the first page
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        reviewElems = soup.select('p.partial_entry')

        if reviewElems:
            for row in reviewElems:
                review_text = row.get_text(strip=True).encode('utf8', 'ignore').decode('latin-1')
                writer.writerow([review_text])
            print('Writing page', pagecounter + 1)
        else:
            print('Could not find clue.')

        # Find URL of next page and update URL
        if pagecounter == 0:
            nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[0]
        elif pagecounter != 0:
            nextLink = soup.select('a[data-offset]')[1]

        URL = 'http://www.tripadvisor.com' + nextLink.get('href')

print('Download complete')
```

Comment: Thank you! That was awesome. :)