# len() function not giving correct character number

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to figure out the number of characters in a string but for some strange reason len() is only giving me back 1. 
here is an example of my output

```
WearWorks is a haptics design company that develops products and 
experiences that communicate information through touch. Our first product, 
Wayband, is a wearable tactile navigation device for the blind and visually 
impaired.
True
1
```

here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url="https://www.wear.works/"
response=requests.get(url)
html=response.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

#reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python
# getting rid of the script sytle in html
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    (script.extract())    # rip it out
    # print(script)

# get text
# grabbing the first chunk of text
text = soup.get_text()[0]
print(isinstance(text, str))
print(len(text))

print(text)
```

Comment: can you please share what does the `type(soup.get_text())` return?

Comment: You've changed the whole question here mate. I am not sure that's advisable. I would recommend you put up another question and revert the changes to this question.

Comment: ok yeah sorry about that will do :)

Comment: ah it wont let me delete it :/

Comment: I've rolled back your update. You can access the edit history and put up a new question for it.

Comment: how do I add a link the the new question?

Comment: ok well i'm going to have to wait 90 minutes for that

Comment: how about `final_required = [t for t in text.split('\n') if t.strip()][0]` right before the `print(text)` and replace `print(text)` with `print(final_required)`? Would it work for you?

Comment: ah it did! thank you so much!!!

Comment: great! Not a problem. `For others: ` Refer to the edit history and see `revision 2` to actually know the reason for the above code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `text = soup.get_text()[0]` convert it to `text = soup.get_text()` have a look. You're slicing a string to get the first character.

Comment: yeah i just realized my question had some issued I'm going to edit it

Comment: @Bob well not a problem, do let me know when you've edited it

Comment: just edited, sorry for the wrong original question. everything should work now when you run my code