# I want to extract text from 1000s of html files with different formats

Tags: python, html

I have 1000s of html files, and I want to extract a section "ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS" from those files. None of the files have any ids or anything and most of them have a different format like, some of them have text in "div" tags, others have it in "p", "table", etc.

Given a specific format, I am able to extract a section of text. For example, [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/4977/000095014409001463/g17619e10vk.htm#103); I was able to extract the the text from the section ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS using this piece of code.

```
should_print = False

for item in soup.find_all("div"):
    if (item.name == "div" and item.parent.name != "div"):
        if "ITEM" in item.text and "1A" in item.text and "RISK" in item.text and "FACTORS" in item.text:
            should_print = True
        elif "ITEM" in item.text and "1B" in item.text:
            break
        if should_print:
            with open(r"RF.html", "a") as f:
                f.write(str(item))
```

I can write a code to cater to all the formats but how will I identify what code to run on which file?
Suppose, if I run this^ code on the file which contains the text in "p" tags, it would give me rubbish text.

[Here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/766421/000119312509033073/d10k.htm#tx21848_26) and [here](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1219601/000119312511050127/d10k.htm) are some more examples of html files.

Comment: this is intriguing, never seen a question relative to this. Definitely interesting, Im sad i cant help you out though as I dont know much js. I have a question similar to this, so i hope someone gives a good answer.

Comment: The question is too generic. Do you know what sections do you want to extract? Do you want just `ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS` sections?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz yes, only the section ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS.
I'll edit my question. :)

Comment: You can try to meta-analyze the texts - if they have lots of text in between P's use that else try DIVs ...

Comment: Please, add a couple of other link to examples.

Comment: My suggestion: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python) to extract the data and *then* go regex on it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your if condition because you are doing just false to true but item in loop is still refers to `soup.find_all("div")`

Change if conditiom to :

```
  if "ITEM" in item.text and "1A" in item.text and "RISK" in item.text and "FACTORS" in item.text:
        print (item.find('b').text)
```

Output :

```
ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS.
```

In if statement :

> print (item.text) will show all text
>
> print (item) will show all source who has a string ITEM , 1A,RISK

Answer (score 0):

A good option would be to look for the section title using **XPath**, that could provide a generic solution. Below, an example using `xmllint` in bash but `xml.etree.ElementTree` in python should do the work

```
xmllint -html -recover -xpath '//div[descendant-or-self::*[.="ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS."]]/descendant-or-self::text()' 2>/dev/null 10k.htm
```

Xpath explained:

- `//div[descendant-or-self::...` Get a div having a child as defined by the expression (explained below).
- `descendant-or-self::*[.="ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS."]` find any node containing the expected title.
- `descendant-or-self::text()` Get text for all contained elements.

Xpath to detect title using `contains(...)`

```
'//div[descendant-or-self::text()[contains(.,"ITEM 1A. RISK FACTORS")]]/descendant-or-self::text()'
```