# reading in multiple text file extensions .pdf, .txt and .htm

Tags: python

I have a folder where I want to read all the text files from and put them into a corpus, however I am only able to do it with .txt files. How can I expand the code below to read in .pdf, .htm and .txt files?

```
corpus_raw = u""
    for file_name in file_names:
        with codecs.open(file_name, "r", "utf-8") as file_name:
            corpus_raw += file_name.read()
        print("Document is {0} characters long".format(len(corpus_raw)))
        print()
```

For example:

```
with open ('/data/text_file.txt', "r", encoding =  "utf-8") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Read in data where I can view it on a notebook.

```
with open ('/data/text_file.pdf', "r", encoding =  "utf-8") as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Read nothing.

Comment: Doing a `read` on a `.pdf` or `.html` and appending what you get to a string won't give you the results you want. They are not textfiles and contain far more than just a series of words. And a `.pdif` is a compressed binary file from which the text will need to be extracted. For `.html.` look at the module `BeautifulSoup`. For `.pdf`s try `textract`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of files, binary files and plain-text files. A file can have one or the other, or sometimes both.

Html files are plaintext, human readable files, which you can edit by hand, but PDF Files are binary + Text files where you'll need special programs to edit them.

If you want to read from pdf or html, it's possible. I wasn't sure if you meant to extract the text, or to extract the source code, so I'll provide explanations to both.

## Extracting Text

Extracting text can be done easily for html files. Using `webbrowser`, you can open your file in the browser, and then use urllib for extracting text. For more info, refer to the answers **here:** [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

For pdf files, you can use a python module called PyPDF2. Download it using pip:
`$ pip install PyPDF2`
and get started.
Here is an example of a simple program I found on the internet:

```
import PyPDF2 

# creating a pdf file object 
pdfFileObj = open('example.pdf', 'rb') 

# creating a pdf reader object 
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj) 

# printing number of pages in pdf file 
print(pdfReader.numPages) 

# creating a page object 
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0) 

# extracting text from page 
print(pageObj.extractText()) 

# closing the pdf file object 
pdfFileObj.close()
```

## Extracting Source Code

Extracting source code is best done using python's `open` function as you did above. 
For html files, you can just do what you did with text files. Or maybe to be simpler,

```
file = open("c:\\path\\to\\file")
print(file.read())
```

you can just do the above.

For pdf files, you do pretty much the same, but specifying the mode for editing in a different parameter in the `open` function. For more info, visit the sites in the More Info section.

```
file = open("c:\\path\\to\\file.extension", "a") #specifies the mode of editing. Unfortunately, you'll only be able to store data, not display it. But you can edit it, then save it after wards
print(file.readable()) #Will return false, proving to be not readable.
file.save("c:\\path\\to\\save\\in.extension")
```

## More Info

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/
- https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/open

Answer (score -1):

This should work for htm/html files with no problem - they are basically just text files. Above, I only see that reading in .pdf has failed - was there a problem with .htm?

Also, reading in a .pdf may be much more difficult/involved than you think. A pdf contains a lot more information than just plaintext, and cannot be meaningfully edited in, say, notepad. As an example of what I mean, here's a small sample of what I got when I opened a .pdf in notepad:

```
%PDF-1.7
%âãÏÓ
1758 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 401/Length 908/N 51/Type/ObjStm>>stream
hÞ”ØQk\7à¿2ÍK,i4
Cã(Á”¾•–öâ.Ýn‚w]òó3rm˜Ÿ =ÄÜÝèÎ‘®?ÉÍ…e¦ê?Å/2e¥ÂJÙˆ+SÉT«ù7$"T„ZËT”´ù2£®L~©¯fÊ©±É–iÌ(¦ÄF¹&OðÑ’Œ|hnžU}Žñ¾®ûDOÉæCÄç'¿IF¸/±Å¿”±/ÿ!¾›Ú˜Æ>¤ùeiêóuÚ3õ®äUÌ˜Ô·’Ìhì´$!_Êœ3©o­úaÇÖÅÏç·rGòuê‡Gé¾é>Žà›ì¾õä›ò£Õì›ðÑµx¨ùQXÇ3ð'åC=ªJÃ6óç:¯ÖýÂ—ZòóúI¹ù…Ÿ3—ñ$<Éw‘èÍ›«›/Ç³/¸z¿¿?Ço'ÑoW¿îÆõXçŸ®¯}Ý»ítþ#?~ö¥ç_ü”×éÓÕÇíÛyü6Ç÷·»ûÍ‡åòøé÷ýù°ýôöá´?n§}8ž·Ãa·ÿÜ>ßÞo‡ý¿§Wat£õ…Ñ~ûÏ[ýQÌÍß»¯çížRŽI
$L’ù¤“úËI%Ã$OâTHb˜dóI5&$(éé´SI“€ˆE”-&Š("4&E”=$1ÁPDYa1   ˆ`(‚çEä“€†"x^DŽÁ@C</"ÇŽ` ¢B</"ÇŽ¨@D…"x^DŽQˆ
EÔ±#*Q¡ˆº "vD"*QDÄŽ¨@„@uADì"Š¨"bG!P„Ì‹(±#ˆ(BæE”ØD!ó"Jì"!ó"JìˆD4(BæE”Ø
ˆhPD[;¢
Šh"bG4 ¢AmADìˆD(ÑDÄŽP B¡ˆ¶ "v„
Eè¼Ž¡@„B:/‚cG(¡P„Î‹àØ
Dt(BçEpìˆDt(BçEpìˆDt(¢/ˆˆÑˆEô±#:Ñ¡ˆ¾ "vD"Šè"bGaPD_;Â€ƒ"l^Da@„A6/¢ÆŽ0 Â ›QcG1Þ¡¨y5–DN    eA6¢Ö‹¬‚² ‹ç#O…ÉEzQ•ð›ª´@£]„¡wU ¿¬J:ô"ñPüŸÑçSÿ(íÃñ¯íÛÿA?û°§7¿8ìBÀawü‡nww›ßû]€ %“xw
endstream
endobj
1759 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/First 1907/Length 3450/N 200/Type/ObjStm>>stream
```

There are, however, options. I would suggest reading the page at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/ as a starting point.

Comment: As insightful this answer might be, this still doesn't solve the problem presented rather giving a direction to a solution. Content-wise, this should be converted to a comment as it is simply not an *answer*...