# How to read saved google search result page?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I search some text in google and saved the page in html.

However, when I opened it, the content disappeared.

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s-93Eo-hB2qzfFZ0v7Y5de4uC8MBmb1J) of my saved html.

What can I do to restore the content?

```
with open('sample.html', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

'万象城上海首秀' in text # False, but it should be True
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I read the file but I cannot find the content it should have.

Comment: This post may be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for this. Here is how to do it:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> soup = bs(open("file.html","r").read(), "html.parser")
>>> '万象城上海首秀' in soup.text
True
>>>
```