# How to extract data from HTML tags using python

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to extract data from resumes. Im using pypandoc to convert docx to HTML.Below is the code which I used.
HTML file obtained is as below.
Can someone explain how to extract Work Histroy from this?

```
import pypandoc

output = pypandoc.convert_file('E:/cvparser/backupresumes/xyz.docx', 'html', outputfile="E:/cvparser/abc.html")

assert output == ""

print(output)
```

Here is the html file:

```
<p>PROFILE SUMMARY</p>

<ul>

<li><p>4 years of experience working in corporate environment as a full stack developer. Strong technical skills in complex website development including web based application.</p></li>

<li><p>ERP application development &amp; enhancement, service delivery and client relationship management in education and industrial domain.</p></li>

</ul>

<p>EDUCATION</p>

<p>MCA (Master of Computer Applications) from CMR Institute of Management Studies – Bangalore University with 78%</p>

<p>BCA (Bachelor of Computer Applications) from Shri SVK College of Business and Management studies - Gulbarga University with 74%.</p>

<p>TECHNICAL SKILLS</p>

<p>Web Technologies: HTML/HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, Ajax, JSON, Apache, Bootstrap.</p>

<p>WORK HISTORY</p>

<ul>

<li><p>Leviosa Consulting Pvt Ltd from Feb 2015 to till date as a sr. Software Developer.</p></li>

<li><p>DRDO – Defence Research and Development Organization from Nov 2014 to Feb 2015 as a contract engineer.</p></li>

</ul>

<p>PROJECTS</p>

<p><strong>I1ERP – Manufacturing Industry</strong></p>

<p>Technologies Used: PHP, MySQL, HTML, CSS, Ajax, Bootstrap, Angular 6.</p>

<p>Duration: 1 Year.</p>

<ul>

<li><p>I1ERP is a fully custom designed application software which itself builds another application without writing code.</p></li>

<li><p>Anyone having knowledge of computer can use this app and build application based on the user requirements.</p></li>

<li><p>This automate and streamline business processes with greater adoptability.</p></li>

<li><p>I1ERP integrates all facets of an operation including product planning, manufacturing, sales, invoice, marketing and Human Resource.</p></li>

</ul>

This software has modules like Document Mgmt., Reminder System, Checklist System, Work Tracking System and Password Mgmt.</p>

<p>PERSONAL DETAILS</p>

<p>Date of Birth: 5<sup>th</sup> Feb 1990</p>

<p>Marital Status: Unmarried</p>

<p>Nationality: Indian</p>

<p>Languages Known: English, Kannada, Telugu and Hindi.</p>
```

Can someone explain how to extract Work History from this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself, so far?

Comment: I'm stuck here. Could you please help me by providing some suggestions@jasie

Comment: @SampathShanbhag Can `beautifulsoup` be used?

Comment: @AndrejKesely can you help me out here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using `beautifulsoup`. Variable `data` contains the HTML text from the question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ *:not(p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ p, p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ p ~ *)'):
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

Prints:

```
Leviosa Consulting Pvt Ltd from Feb 2015 to till date as a sr. Software Developer.
DRDO – Defence Research and Development Organization from Nov 2014 to Feb 2015 as a contract engineer.
```

Comment: @SampathShanbhag make sure you have latest version of `beautifulsoup` installed. I'm on version `beautifulsoup4==4.8.0`

Comment: But for below html it won’t help
<p><strong><span class="underline">EXPERIENCE DETAILS</span></strong></p>
<p>- Currently working as an ‘<strong>Android Developer</strong>’ in Deuglo Technologies Pvt. Ltd., Bangalore. (From Feb 17).</p>
<p>- Worked as a ‘Software Engineer’ in Impressol e-Services LLP, Bangalore. (From Jan 2016 - Jan 2017)</p>

Comment: @SampathShanbhag It's necessary to adjust CSS selector. Unfortunately, I don't know how every document is structured so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: How can we write a function for below HTML @Andrej Kesely:                                  <p><strong>EXPERIENCE SUMMARY:</strong></p>
<p>Over 5+ years of total IT experience in enterprise/mobile applications development using Google Android SDK.</p>
<p> Effective in interacting with customers to understand the requirements.</p>

<p>• Very strong in Object Oriented Concepts and Programming.</p>
<p>• Adhere to Agile methodology work environment<strong>.</strong></p>
<p><strong>TECHNICAL SKILLS:</strong></p>
<p><strong>Programming</strong>: - Core Java, Android</p>

Answer (score 0):

```
import pypandoc

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



output = pypandoc.convert_file('E:/cvparser/backupresumes/Bapuray.docx', 'html', outputfile="E:/cvparser/Bap.html")

assert output == ""



with open('E:/cvparser/Bap.html') as report:

    raw = report.readlines()

    str = """""".join(raw)

    #print(str)

soup = BeautifulSoup(str, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ *:not(p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ p, p:contains("WORK HISTORY") ~ p ~ *)'):

    print(tag.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
```

I got the below error:
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type