# how to convert html text into plain text using pyspark? Replacing html tags from string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one text file in which there is one column 'descn' which has some text but they are in html format. So i want to convert html text into plain text using pyspark. Please help me to do this.

file name:

```
mdcl_insigt.txt
```

input:

```
PROTEUSÂ <div><br></div><div>We are struggling with pathology. We don&#39;t control specimens of prostatectomy. The hospital pathology is not cooperating. I am reaching out to another hospital. You have pretty intense manual guidelines on pathology in the [PROTEUS] protocol for managing of RP [specimens]. Please e-mail me with work around options.</div>
```

it should convert like this, output:

```
PROTEUS We are struggling with pathology. We don't control specimens of prostatectomy. The hospital pathology is not cooperating. I am reaching out to another hospital. You have pretty intense manual guidelines on pathology in the [PROTEUS] protocol for managing of RP [specimens]. Please e-mail me with work around options.
```

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is in python. i want solution in pyspark.

Comment: You can do any type of python coding in pyspark @abhishek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing a [regexp_replace()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df = df.withColumn("parsed_descn", regexp_replace("descn", "<[^>]+>", ""))
```

The regex is not perfect and might fail. Please do some more research to make it better.

It worked on your sample string, when I tried it on [regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Pyspark output:

```
df.withColumn("parsed", F.regexp_replace("descn", "<[^>]+>", "")).select("parsed").collect()

[Row(parsed='PROTEUSÂ We are struggling with pathology. We don&#39;t control specimens of prostatectomy. The hospital pathology is not cooperating. I am reaching out to another hospital. You have pretty intense manual guidelines on pathology in the [PROTEUS] protocol for managing of RP [specimens]. Please e-mail me with work around options.')]
```

Comment: hi @pissall , thank you for reply. Can you please elaborate more? i'm not able to understand your code.

Comment: @abhishek What part do you not understand? I used a regular expression to find all html tags and then replaced them with an empty string.

Comment: actually this column is present in text file (mdcl_insigt.txt). So can you tell me how to read this text file and convert the html text into plain text of descn column.

Comment: The Q&A is specific to removing HTML tags from the text in a column in pyspark. For anything else you can ask another question. You can close this question by selecting the tick on the left of the answer. And please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i accepted your answer. Can you please tell me how to read text file in pyspark?