# Reformat line/div extracted from html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, extract

I am currently having trouble re-formating a div that I extracted from a website.

This is what I currently have:

```
<div class=" frame frame-default frame-type-textmedia frame-layout-0" id="c47903"><a id="c47904"/><div class="ce-textpic ce-left ce-above"><div class="ce-bodytext"><p>The latest data of the evolution of COVID-19 over the past 24hours <strong>in Québec</strong> reveal:</p><ul><li>87new cases, bringing the total number of infected persons to61,004;</li><li>no deaths have occurred in the past 24hours, to which are added 3deaths which occurred between August7 and12, for a total of5,718;</li><li>the number of hospitalizations increased by2 compared to the previous day, for a cumulative total of151. Of these, 25were in intensive care, an increase of2;</li><li>18,596tests were performed on August12, for a cumulative total of1,428,286.</li></ul></div></div></div>
```

but I would like to have something similar to this:

The latest data of the evolution of COVID-19 over the past 24hours in Québecreveal: 87new cases, bringing the total number of infected persons to61,004; no deaths have occurred in the past 24hours, to which are added 3deaths which occurred between August7 and12, for a total of5,718; the number of hospitalizations increased by2 compared to the previous day, for a cumulative total of151. Of these, 25were in intensive care, an increase of2;18,596tests were performed on August12, for a cumulative total of1,428,286.

I removed it manually, but does there exists something that is less time consuming?

Comment: Have you tried using `get_text()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting text from HTML file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328356/extracting-text-from-html-file-using-python)

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Just a bunch of str(div).replace("what I want gone","")

Comment: If you've captured the tag with `bs4`, try using `get_text()` on the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
text = r'<div class=" frame frame-default frame-type-textmedia frame-layout-0" id="c47903"><a id="c47904"/><div class="ce-textpic ce-left ce-above"><div class="ce-bodytext"><p>The latest data of the evolution of COVID-19 over the past 24hours <strong>in Québec</strong> reveal:</p><ul><li>87new cases, bringing the total number of infected persons to61,004;</li><li>no deaths have occurred in the past 24hours, to which are added 3deaths which occurred between August7 and12, for a total of5,718;</li><li>the number of hospitalizations increased by2 compared to the previous day, for a cumulative total of151. Of these, 25were in intensive care, an increase of2;</li><li>18,596tests were performed on August12, for a cumulative total of1,428,286.</li></ul></div></div></div>'
import re
print(re.sub(r'<[^<>]*>', ' ', text))
```

Comment: you can try **f"{variableforthevalue}" ** in **Python 3** for **Python 2** you have to use **"%s"%(variableforthevalue)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
soup.select_one('div[class="ce-bodytext"]').text.strip()
```

That should get you your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
str(bs4_obj.select('div')[0].text)
```

I don't know how to convert it from unicode,
but it gets rid of the html tags.