# How to extract modified text of p tag to python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I tried whole day but unable to extract the overwritten texts of p tag.
For example:

```
<p id='demo'><p>
<Script>
  Var = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'some context'
<Script>
```

I need the text 'some context' into python.
I tried with beautifulsoup

`page = soup.find('p').getText()`

I'm getting nothing. Is there any way to get changed text of p tag. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3987802/8133524 i hope it will work

Comment: You will need to actually run the javascript before the 'demo' element gets "some context" inside it.

Comment: `beautifulsoup` don't execute javascript. You have to do request using `Selenium` or another headless browser to be able render html page

Comment: Thanks all, @qrsngky running javascript before 'demo' element also giving me nothing.

Comment: @rzlvmp is right: you can't run javascript just using beautifulsoup. Wherever you put the script tag, it's not executed.

Comment: @rzlvmp I am able to render html page with all changed text made in a p tags using JS, only unable to get that changed text to python

Comment: By "render", you mean in a browser? And how do you run the Python part?

Comment: yes, It rendered in browser, its showing there. I need that text into backend now. @qrsngky

Comment: `yes, It rendered in browser` → `beautifulsoup` is not a browser. Check for `Selenium`