# Regex to read out HTML tags

Tags: html, regex, tags

I'm looking for a regex that matches all used HTML tags in a text consisting of several lines. It should read out "b", "p" and "script" in the following lines:

```
<b>
<p class="normalText">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Is there such thing? The start I have is that it should start with a "<" and read until it hits a space or a ">", but at the same time, it should not include the starting "<" since I just want to match the letter/word itself. Thoughts?

Comment: Seriously, this has been asked so many times before it's not funny.

Comment: @cletus, It might, I'd be happy to see where, and no, the links below are not touching the issue at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's virtually impossible to regex HTML once you start considering all the special cases and malformed HTML that browsers sometimes happilly parse anyway. That said however I thought it might be fun to get the names without using capture groups and thus I present too you with the following sollution:

```
(?<=<)\w+(?=[^<]*?>)
```

For the record I hold little faith in it being at all useful in any but the most trivial of cases.

Comment: It's just made for an example anyway, and doesn't need to be bullet proof. This worked perfectly, and I see how the exclude function works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @cletus: On what level is this wrong that he did not already cover?

Answer (score 6):

There are many similar questions on SO:

1. [Filter out HTML tags and resolve entities in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486/filter-out-html-tags-and-resolve-entities-in-python)
2. [Regex to match all HTML tags except <p> and </p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869/regex-to-match-all-html-tags-except-p-and-p)
3. [Strip all HTML tags except links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44078/strip-all-html-tags-except-links)

etc. The general agreement is that it's best not to use regular expressions to parse HTML instead of doing it properly by applying a DOM parser and traversing the DOM tree.

Comment: You might want to change that link text from the URL to the question text so it's more readable.

Comment: Yea, I have seen them. I'm not really worried about best practice here though since it's not gonna end up in an application anyway. The biggest problem I see with what I want is to match the first char "<" but not include it in the match, if that makes sense.

Comment: @miccet: use parentheses to group the stuff you are interested in.

Comment: @cletus: I might, but I'm a lazy bastard. Besides, it's not really the title that matters, given that they are all related to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what system you are using, but it can be done to a certain extent. Look at [this](http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start) online flex-based application. Check out the Published > XML regex examples. You will get an idea.

Comment: Can't find an example that helps me with the problem, but it's a great resource! I'm using ASP.net regex.