# Python convert html ascii encoded text to utf8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, html-entities

I have a xml file, which I need to convert to utf8.
Unfortunately the entities contain text like this:

```
&#047;mytext&#044;
```

I'm using the codec library to convert files to utf8, but html entities won't work with it.

Is there an easy way to get rid of the html encoding?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486/filter-out-html-tags-and-resolve-entities-in-python

Comment: Can you just pass the raw file through an unescape first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the text of the file through an [unescape](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html) function before passing it to the XML parser.

Alternatively, if you're only parsing HTML, [lxml's http parser](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) does this for you:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> html = lxml.html.fromstring("<html><body><p>&#047;mytext&#044;</p></body></html>")
>>> lxml.html.tostring(html)
'<html><body><p>/mytext,</p></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently posted the below in response to a similar question:

```
import HTMLParser     # html.parser in Python 3
h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
h.unescape('&#047;mytext&#044;')
```

Technically this method is "internal" and undocumented, but it's been in the API quite a while and isn't marked with a leading underscore.

Found it [here](http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/); other approaches are also mentioned, of which BeautifulSoup is probably the best if you don't mind its "heaviness."